# If a brokerage commits fraud (by not separating customer funds), is there any SIPC protection?

Tags: united-states, broker, bankruptcy, sipc

Recent news on [MF Global](http://dealbook.nytimes.com/2011/10/31/regulators-investigating-mf-global/) suggests the possibility that the brokerage firm did **not** segregate customer accounts.

Suppose I have an account at MF Global and suppose they have failed to segregate my account.  The company goes bankrupt.

Would the SIPC protect me in this case?

What if I were a company with more than $500k at the brokerage?  Would all funds above $500k be lost?

Comment: The amount over 500k may not be lost but the SIPC will not reimburse for it.  Its possible they would be able to recover some or all of it though anyone betting on it... well I'd love to cover that bet.  Of course there has been some recent history of the government stepping in and realigning the rules about who gets repaid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SIPC would protect individual investors up to $500K for securities & cash, with a max of $250K for cash. One would receive all securities that are already in your name or in the process.

In case client money was diverted to company trades, then SIPC will investigate and try to find out how much money belonged to each customer. It would determine this on various inputs including your transaction records like money to transferred to MF Global, internal records, amongst other things.

More information in the SIPC bulletin: http://www.sipc.org/Media/NewsReleases/release31Oct2011.aspx

Comment: MF Global was a futures and derivatives firm though and futures are not considered securities.